# System policy prevents changes, contact system administrator- Ubuntu 19.10 .?

Tags: drivers, server

Recently we have implemented **ubuntu 19.10**. after putting it live when I tried to change the System setting to enable Automatic Time and Date to enable. Its showing a unlock button above and gives a message *system policy prevents contact system administrator*. I tried following commands through terminal

```
timedatectl status
timedatectl set-ntp 1
sudo service ntp start
sudo apt-get install ntp
```

but still the problem exists

How can I make this thing enable Automatic Time and Date to get enable. Please help me with a solution

Comment: Why are Ubuntu 12.04 & 14.04 tagged when you question specifically mentions 19.10?  On Stack Overflow you tagged 19.04 too?  Why do you think kernel modules are involved (ie. drivers?)  https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/NTP.html

Comment: cause I didnt get 19.10 tag ...  this is the terminal output when I run 

adssys@aroorlinux:~$ timedatectl status
               Local time: Sat 2020-02-15 15:11:20 IST
           Universal time: Sat 2020-02-15 09:41:20 UTC
                 RTC time: Sat 2020-02-15 09:41:20
                Time zone: Asia/Kolkata (IST, +0530)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: inactive
          RTC in local TZ: no
adssys@aroorlinux:~$ @guiverc